# .net core key vault link fails with Access Forbidden on local environment

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am running the following functionality as a part of Main method of my .net core web application

```
private static void LinkKeyVault(IConfigurationBuilder config, string keyVaultEndpoint)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
            {
                var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
            }
        }
```

When I am running this code on my local dev machine I am getting the following error "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'". When this code runs in Azure under app service user assigned managed identity everything works just fine. On my local environment I am logged in with my Azure AD user which was granted access permissions using key vault access policy, the permissions are the same as for user assigned managed identity.

[image]

[image]

dfrds-dev-web-identity is the user assigned managed identity, DFRDDevelopers is a group that my Azure AD account is a part of.

Comment: Could you share the screenshot of your access policy?

Comment: Added screenshot, dfrds-dev-web-identity is the user assigned managed identity, DFRDDevelopers is a group that my Azure AD account is a part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, please make sure the group in which the user account located is a `Security` group, not a `Microsoft 365` group, just the `Security` group is supported in this feature.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/secure-your-key-vault#data-plane-and-access-policies

> To grant data plane access to several users, create an **Azure AD security group** and add users to that group.

Also, if you want to use Visual Studio to auth, make sure you logged in with the correct account, and try to use [`RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=VisualStudio`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support) in the code to make sure it uses the Visual Studio to auth.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider(RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=VisualStudio);
```

Comment: Basically without changing anything in the code it started to work. Even there's no need for connection string. I guess the problem was some local cache by visual studio. I logged out and logged in using my Azure AD account and it started to work.